# Remove focus on first textbox

Tags: windows-8, textbox, windows-store-apps

In our Windows Store app we have a textbox, and when the application starts this textbox always get focus. In a desktop scenario that's no problem, but on a tablet device this focus will directly open the onscreen keyboard which is not a scenario that we want.

We tried to set the focus on another control programmatic with the .Focus(FocusState) method, but somehow the focus is set back to the textbox. We have both set the focus in the  LoadState or the OnNavigatedTo method.

Only when we have timer we have set the focus succesfully to another control. Anyone has ideas how to set the focus to another control, or preferably set not focus at all to an control?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Normally you can set the Focus on any element by `TextBox.Focus()`. However I discovered the same behaviors (autofocus on start) when you place your TextBox inside a ScrollViewer or a FlyOut. Then you have to set the [IsTabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.istabstop) on the parent-element:

```
<ScrollViewer IsTabStop="true">
   <TextBox />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It is not the exact answer, because my textbox wasn't inside a scrollviewer or flyout. Although I fixed it by adding a scrollview with IsTabStop=true before the textbox and set the horizontal and -vertical scrollbars visibility to collapsed. It's definitly not the most wonderfull solution, but until I found out what's causing it, it works! Thanks!

Comment: IsTabStop is a Control property. So you can set it on any control. Maybe you just try to set it on you current parent element (whatever it is).

Comment: It's a Grid inside a LayoutAwarePage. Grid doesn't have IsTabStop. LayoutAwarePage has, but that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

IsTabStop="true" didn't work for me. My solution is to call UpdateLayout() of the scrollViewer before setting the focus on the TextBox:

scrollViewer.UpdateLayout();

textBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like accepted answer with the `ScrollViewer` you can also do this to remove the focus:

```
_textBox.IsReadOnly = true;
_textBox.IsReadOnly = false;
```