# Why default border comes for list view in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using list view template in Universal windows platform, I hope i am doing everything right, but when the app loads for the first time , in the list view first item is having a black border.[image]

What i did in UI is

```
         <Page
x:Class="ListViewExample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ListViewExample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:ListViewExample.Model" 
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="BookListDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:Book">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image Name="image" Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" />
            <StackPanel Margin="20,20,0,0"  Width="100">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Width="auto" />
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{x:Bind Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Width="auto" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="stylez">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <RelativePanel >

        <Button Name="hambergerbutton" FontSize="36" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Click="hambergerbutton_Click" ></Button>
        <StackPanel Background="Gray"></StackPanel>
        <TextBlock  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" 
                    FontSize="24">Books</TextBlock>

    </RelativePanel>


    <SplitView Grid.Row="1" Name="myspliview"
               DisplayMode="CompactInline"  OpenPaneLength="200" 
               CompactPaneLength="56" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox SelectionMode="single" Name="listicons" SelectionChanged="listicons_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xe72D;" FontSize="36" />
                        <TextBlock Text="share" FontSize="24" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xe724;" FontSize="36" />
                        <TextBlock Text="favourites" FontSize="24" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem></ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,20,20,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
               Name="ResultTextBlock" 
               FontSize="24" 
               Foreground="Red" 
               FontWeight="Bold" 
               Margin="20,20,0,0" />
                <!--<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Books}" 
              ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookListDataTemplate}">
                </ListView>-->

                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Books}" 
              ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            Width="auto" Grid.Column="0" 
                              RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate IsTabStop="true" Style="{StaticResource  stylez}" >
                        <DataTemplate  x:DataType="data:Book"  >
                            <StackPanel   Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="0" >
                                <Image Name="image" Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" />
                                <StackPanel Margin="20,20,0,0" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="16" MinWidth="100" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" MinWidth="100"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </Grid>



        </SplitView.Content>


    </SplitView>


</Grid>
```

Why this border is coming how to get rid of these? i was following this tutorial 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-040-Data-Binding-to-the-GridView-and-ListView-Controls

How to fix this problem, i dont want any default border

Comment: the black border gets disappear when i click any, and the clicked will be highlighted .

Comment: i am using visual studio 2015 community edition, and running it in local machine.

Comment: `<ListView.ItemTemplate IsTabStop="true" Style="{StaticResource  stylez}" >` is wrong. You need to assign `stylez` to `ItemContainerStyle` of the `ListView` itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dark border you see comes from the default `Style` of the `ListViewItem`.

By default, *system* focus visuals are in use with `UseSystemFocusVisuals` set to `True`. Setting it to `False` will make the control use control-level focus visual (*dotted lines* by default) instead.

So there are a few ways to remove/hide them all together. Normally I just change the *thickness* of the system visuals to `0`, like this -

```
<ListView TabNavigation="Cycle">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Also setting `<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />` will hide the focus visuals however keep in mind tab naviation will stop working after doing so.

If your app is on XBox or expected to be used with keyboards, I'd recommand to leave the focus visuals as they are or maybe change the `FocusVisualPrimaryBrush` and `FocusVisualSecondaryBrush` to more subtle colors.

Comment: im getting this error when i used this method.


Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  'Unexpected 'ATTRIBUTE' in parse rule 'NonemptyPropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG.'.' Line number '92' and line position '48'. Gridview

Comment: @hildasonica what's your windows 10 build and sdk version number?

Comment: target version: windows 10 anniversarry edition build 14393

Comment: let me know where i can check sdk version

Comment: @hildasonica you can check by right click on your uwp project. Can you also show me you xaml?

Comment: how should i share my xaml?

Comment: @hildasonica now your full xaml, just where you have used my code. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145432/discussion-between-hilda-sonica-and-justin-xl).

Comment: Hi justin, please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905132/uwp-app-for-making-system-changes  and please help me with any document or something.

Answer (score 0):

When an app starts the first UI element in the layout that can a have focus gets it. In your case it's the first item of your ListView, that's why there's a black border around it.

Focus is used to enable user interaction with an app using a keyboard: e.g. by pressing arrow keys on your keyboard you're be able to pick different items in your list. If you run this app on a phone that doesn't have a physical keyboard there won't be a border around the first list item.

There's no way to change the focus behaviour for UWP apps but there are some workarounds you might want to look at:
[Stackoverflow - Remove focus on first textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121089/remove-focus-on-first-textbox)
[Stackoverflow - How to not focus element on application startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182664/how-to-not-focus-element-on-application-startup)